# XNA SaveGame "StorageDemo"

Tags: xml, xna

I am attempting to use xml to save stuff such as coins in my game. When I look at the Microsoft support website, I see this snippet of code:

```
// Open a storage container.
IAsyncResult result =
device.BeginOpenContainer("StorageDemo", null, null);

// Wait for the WaitHandle to become signaled.
result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

StorageContainer container = device.EndOpenContainer(result);

// Close the wait handle.
result.AsyncWaitHandle.Close();
```

I was wonder what I was supposed to put in place of "StorageDemo", and also what it means in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can look up method definitions on MSDN which will help explain what's going on in various parts of the API.

Here's the link for StorageDevice.BeginOpenContainer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.storage.storagedevice.beginopencontainer.aspx

You can see on that page that "StorageDemo" is the Display Name parameter and that it's used to pass in a string to name the file.

So in the example you posted, "StorageDemo" is what the name of the file will be saved at in the end.